# Using different Class Methods, depending on the used target compiler option

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

How can I tell TypeScript to use different-written methods (on the same class), depending on the used `target` option within the `tsconfig.json` file?

I'm currently re-writing one of my scripts into TypeScript to just "manage" one source, because at the moment I'm working with an ES5 and an ES6 file next to each other. Since TypeScript supports to just change the output target in the `tsconfig.json` file, I would just need one version to update and maintain.

The problem is I'm using a generator in the ES6 version, which theoretically shouldn't be this issue because TypeScript "adds" a pseudo generator to the top of my ES5 file. BUT: My Pseudo-Generator code, which I'm currently using on the ES5 file, is "cleaner" and way less code.

**The Question**

Is it possible to overwrite the respective "generator" method or using any special comment annotation (such as `//@ts-target`) to tell the compiler which code (function body) should be used depending on the used `target` in the configuration file? (Even If I couldn't found such solution on the official documentation).

An additional function or script, which can be added into the TypeScript compiler process would also help, I guess, because I'm compiling them using a small node.js script (which compiles both ES files without changing the `tsconfig.json` file directly.)

Or is there any kind of extension, to move different methods of the same class into different files? This way I could "extract" the respective "generator" methods, but this would cause another question: How can I link them depending on the target, because I'm using `/// <reference />` linking on the main script file to get all together.

Any other idea?

```js
class Option {
    ///@ts-target ES5
    __walkerVariable1:any undefined
    __walkerVariable2:any undefined
    __walkerVariable3:any undefined
    walker() {
        /* Some Pseudo-Walker Code for ES5 */
    }

    ///@ts-target ES6
    *walker() {
        /* Real Walker Code for ES6 */
    }
}
```

Currently, a Pseudo-Generator code gets added in the ES5 version of my script. I want to prevent this by using a different method / function body with my own Pseudo-Generator. Therefore, I need to tell TypeScript that he should "ignore" the Pseudo-Generator in ES6 / the Real-Generator in ES5 and just render one of them depending on the used `target` option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a bit tricky, but I found a solution thanks to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29226).

As mentioned above, I'm using my own node.js script to compile the TypeScript files into two different JavaScript versions (ES5 and ES6). Therefore, I'm using the TypeScript API with the `ts.createProgram` method. This method allows to add a host object as third parameter, which takes over some compiler processes and one of those is the file loader, called `getSourceFile`.

The rest is then relatively easy: Searching for a custom comment annotation (in my case `\\\@ts-target:ES5` and `\\\@ts-target:ES6` respectively) and filter them using RegExp. Maybe not the best solution, but it works!

```js
function compileTS(){
    let config = readConfig("ts/tsconfig.json");
    let host = ts.createCompilerHost(config.options);
    let sourceFile = host.getSourceFile;

    // ES5 JavaScript
    (function(config){
        host.getSourceFile = function(filename) {
            if(filename === "ts/options.ts"){
                let file = fs.readFileSync("./ts/options.ts").toString();
                file = file.replace(/[ ]+\/\/\/\@ts\-target\:ES6\s+([\s\S]*)\/\/\/\@ts\-target\:ES6/gm, "");
                return ts.createSourceFile(filename, file, ts.ScriptTarget.ES5, true);
            }
            return sourceFile.call(host, filename);
        }
        let program = ts.createProgram(config.fileNames, config.options, host);
        let emitResult = program.emit();
        report(ts.getPreEmitDiagnostics(program).concat(emitResult.diagnostics));
        if(emitResult.emitSkipped){
            process.exit(1);
        }
    }(config));

    // ES6 JavaScript
    config.options.target = 2;
    config.options.outFile = "../dist/js/tail.select-es6.js";
    (function(config){
        host.getSourceFile = function(filename) {
            if(filename === "ts/options.ts"){
                let file = fs.readFileSync("./ts/options.ts").toString();
                file = file.replace(/[ ]+\/\/\/\@ts\-target\:ES5\s+([\s\S]*)\/\/\/\@ts\-target\:ES5/gm, "");
                return ts.createSourceFile(filename, file, ts.ScriptTarget.ES2015, true);
            }
            return sourceFile.call(host, filename);
        }
        let program = ts.createProgram(config.fileNames, config.options, host);
        let emitResult = program.emit();
        report(ts.getPreEmitDiagnostics(program).concat(emitResult.diagnostics));
        if(emitResult.emitSkipped){
            process.exit(1);
        }
    }(config));
}
```